# RESTService response

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf

I want my service method to response a string. For example: I want the service method to insert a item on the table, if it got inserted the service method should response a string "True" otherweise "False". How should the method look like?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is... some code examples or a more detailed description of what you are trying to accomplish would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/656/) example. It shows how to return an image from the service, but since it returns binary data, you can also return your text in this way. Hope this helps.